# Reading and returning value from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently trying to read a value from a database that can have a value of 0 or 1. I'm trying to print and return this value but it isn't working. I'm not an experienced programmer and would like to get some help! You can see my code below:

```
    public partial class AlarmsComponent
{
    public string ReadTag(string sTagName, string sValue)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionstring = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=HMI_DB;User ID=sa;Password=sa;";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sValue FROM dbo.ActualData where sTagName = 'plcled_EStop'";
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine("De waarde is: ", sValue);
                    }               
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return sValue;
    }
}
```

I need to return the value from the tag sValue within the database. I've tried to add a Console.WriteLine (see below)

```
Console.WriteLine("De waarde is: ", sValue);
```

The console is printing: "De waarde is:", but it's not printing the desired value.

I'd love to hear from you!

Comment: Your code doesn't fetch any data from the reader - your `sValue` parameter is never changed. I suspect you want `sValue = reader.GetString(0);` or similar. It's worth reflecting on how you *thought* the value of `sValue` would be changed - and what you expect to use the parameter value for. I'd also *strongly* recommend against swallowing exceptions like this.

Comment: You are printing `sValue` which is the method parameter and is not the returned value from the query. Get the value with `reader.GetString(0)` or `GetInt32(0)` or whatever it is. If you have only one record, you can also use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead of a reader.

Comment: You should remove that empty exception handler.  It isn't helping you; it's hindering your ability to diagnose errors in your code.  At a *minimum*, log the exception so you at least know it happened.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's working now!

Comment: The OP solved his problem himself. No answers were given.